# Android App is not running on other devices

Tags: java, android

I just made a simple android app with 2 **buttons**. Each button `onClick` opens a new activity. I installed the app on my device via USB cable from Android studio and it runs fine on my device.

But here rises the problem, when I installed the app on my friends device after sharing via SHAREit the app installed on his device but did not run.

What could be the reason for this? And how can I solve this?

Please help. Thank you

Comment: check settings in your friend's phone, maybe some setting is prevent it.

Comment: did you build apk or just run the project from android studio?

Comment: You have to generate APK file from android studio. then send thi apk to your friend's phone

Comment: APK is generating frim android studio but not working

Comment: it installed successfully then can not open

Comment: You should have your friend provide a logcat or you need to test on other devices. Pick some emulators

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most probably due to the Android instant run features. Try the following steps to get this working,

Step 1: From Android Studio, click on Build => Build APK. Once the build is complete, you will see an option to view the APK in explorer. Copy the app-debug.apk to a folder of your choice.

Step 2: Open a command line. Switch to the folder which contains app-debug.apk. Run the following command to install your APK on phone,

```
adb install -r app-debug.apk
```

Step 3: From your phone, use Share-it to copy the APK to your friend's phone. Now the app should run.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening sometime, when do some changes in app configuration/ gradle by unknowingly,

**DO THIS THING FOR SOULUTION:**

1. Close Project in Android Studio.
2. Close Android Studio completely.
3. Rename your Project name.
4. Open Studio and import Project
5. Clean and Try to Run